# How do i place this menu at the bottom right of its parent div?

Tags: html, css, positioning, absolute

I've been trying to absolutely position my navigation at the bottom right of its parent div (header>nav>menu) and i'm a little lost. Help would be appreciated!

I've been trying to relatively position its parent div, but each property i try, it either disappears from the browser, aligns all the way at the bottom right of the page and not its parent div, or somewhere else i'm not wanting it to go.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <header>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.png" / id="logo">
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="career.html">Career</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>             
            </nav>
        </header>

    </div>

</body>
</html>

body {
    margin:auto;
    width:960px;
}

.logo {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:242px;
    height:141px;
    margin:0px;
}



#header {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}

#nav .menu {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    float:right;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style:none;
}

#menu li {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}

#menu a {
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#98bf21;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

#menu a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#7A991A;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made some mistakes,

1. you use `#header` in css but you don't put id header to the `<header>` tag,
2. you use `#nav` in css instead of nav tag because there is no id in `nav` tag,
3. `#header` height is 100%. it will take the height of parent. put `height:auto;` so that it will take only the height it need to fit its content.

I made a JSFiddle. please check. hope this will solve your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/banded_krait/Q4Zjj/

Comment: Thank you so much, bandedKrait!

I see what i did there thanks to you! Simple problems lead to complex anxiety haha. <3

Answer (score 2):

you define in your css `nav` is a `tag element` not `id` or `menu` is a `id` not `class`  Please change to your css and define as like this

**Change to this**

```
#nav .menu
```

**into this**

```
nav #menu
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9NNDD/1/)**

Comment: I appreciate the help, however, i tried this and it moves it to the bottom right of the screen.

Maybe i need to add height to its parent div?

Comment: This is where I'm at: http://jsfiddle.net/dRPyJ/

Still not properly showing up. I think it is off the screen above the wrapper.